# Using Stripe in a CoffeeScript file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, stripe-payments

I have a CoffeeScript file called `subscribers.coffee.erb`

```
$(document).ready -> 
  stripe = require('stripe')('<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]%>')

  $('.pricing-get-started').prop("disabled", true)
  $('.verify-coupon').click ->
    # use stripe api to verify that the coupon is valid

  return
return
```

The second line does not seem to be working. I have even tried to copy and past my publishable key but that doesn't work either. I think the following problems are:

1. `require('stripe')` isn't found
2. Rails cannot locate the publishable key from the coffeescript file

**Note:**

I have a working key. I can sign up for subscriptions and everything from my subscribers/new.html.haml.

I am using `gem 'stripe'`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @muistooshort I edited that issue and fixed it. That wasn't in my actual code (must of gotten deleted when I was moving some stuff around in the editor on here). Anyways, do you have any other suggestions as to why this is not working? Is there another way I can access the publishable key or stripe.js?

Comment: Is it that `require` isn't working or that `require` can't find Stripe?

Comment: @muistooshort I am not sure. I am using `gem stripe` and from the looks of it, it seems that the `stripe.js` file should be available in the asset pipeline. That is why I thought `require` might be working and there was an issue with rails finding the `publishable_key`

Comment: Any errors anywhere? Are you sure `Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]` is right when you're compiling assets?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `stripe = require('stripe')`, but `require` isn't defined by default in javascript. As long as you have `stripe.js` included in your application before this script is called the `require('stripe')` line should be unnecessary.

Once Stripe.js is loaded you can set your publishable key via `Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_key_here');`. If you're using an environment variable, be sure that `Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]` is defined in your environment.

Finally, you should be aware that any embedded ruby in an asset file included in your asset manifest (`application.js` or `application.css`) will not be called on each request, but will only be called when you run `rake assets:precompile`. Thus `Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]` may not always evaluate to a value you expect.